# In WSS 3.0 is it possible to show folders at the bottom of a document library

Tags: document-library, wss-3.0, sorting

I have explained the reasons against using folders in general, but I have been asked to get a definitive answer as to whether there is any way to stop folders in a WSS 3 Document Library from appearing at the top...

Is it possible to make the folders appear at the bottom, after any files that are at the same level?

Alternatively is it possible to have folders ordered by name amongst any documents at the same level, at the moment folders always appear at the top, they won't "mix" in with the files into alphabetic order.

I don't think this is possible, but hoping to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to show folders along with files at the same level is to disable the New Folder command. i.e Make "New Folder" command available?  But I wonder whether you would like to disable that.